# Automatically restart configuration on source code change

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, hotswap

I've got simple application which builds into jar and starts in 2-3 seconds.
 Is it possible to configure Intellij IDEA to rebuild/restart configuration on any source code change (it differs from hotswap)?

Comment: How does this differ from hotswap please? There is something here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/reloading-classes.html - but it is called hotswap.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be perfectly solved by DCEVM+Hotswap-Agent technologies.Look at this project: https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent